# CSS in Angular project: position: fixed not always functioning as expected

Tags: html, css, angular, css-position, sticky

I am having issues with my sticky table header in my angular 6 project.

I have a condition in my .ts file that applies the 'sticky' class only when the user scrolls towards a certain point in the page. That part works great. The issue is that when the position: fixed class is applied, it only works if top:0.
The css looks like this:

```
.sticky
    {
        position: fixed;
        top:0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding-right: 20px!important;

    }
```

But if I change top:0 to top:100, too account for the header of the webpage (that is build on another component) then the top:100 attribute won't apply and be considered invalid.

The html is a little tricky but looks a little like this

child.component.html

```
<div>
  <navigation></navigation>
  <div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-responsive " >
        <table id="tabletop" #tabletop class="table scroll">
            <thead #stickyMenu [class.sticky]="sticky">
                 <tr id="content" class="row1">
                 <tr id="content" class="row2">
                 <tr id="content" class="row3">
            </thead>
       </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

app.component.html

```
<header></header>
  <app-child></app-child>
<footer></footer>
```

I want the thead to stick right underneath the header that lives on a parent component, so it is still visible.

Why is that, and how can I get my position:fixed attribute to actually keep something at the top of the page?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think you're looking for `position: sticky`? `fixed` positions it relative to the viewport, which doesn't sound like it's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post this by comment, but looks like I need at least 50 reputation to do so. So, here it goes:

> But if I change top:0 to top:100 {...}

The [unit](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) of the `top` seems to be missing. You probably wanted to set it to `100px`? Probably the `0` value confused you as it is allowed with or without a unit.

One more thing, the id of each element must be unique, but you have 3 `id="content"` there.

---

**Alternative solution**

You can use `position: sticky` css property on your `thead` element (and also on the respective `th` child elements). This way, you wouldn't need to handle the scroll event by yourself and let the css do the job for you.

Example:

I only include the scss part here, since the code snippets make the post unnecessarily long. You can see full example on [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-rk4r53).

```css
thead {
    position: sticky; 
    top: 0px;

    tr {
      position: sticky; top: 0; 

      /* the top value can be adjusted according to <header>'s height */
      &:nth-child(1) th { position: sticky; top: 110px; }   
      &:nth-child(2) th { position: sticky; top: 132px; }
    }
}
```